# Many RabbitMQ brokers and one celery application

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

I have a many RabbitMQ brokers and single Celery application.
I would like to route all messages from all brokers to this single application. What is the simplest way to do this?

I know that it can be done by creating a federation between RabbitMQ brokers and I would like to know is there another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do this in Celery. There is an option to provide list of brokers, but it will be used for failover strategy. Read more [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#broker-settings)

```
broker_url = [
    'transport://userid:password@localhost:port//',
    'transport://userid:password@hostname:port//'
]
```